# Mule 3.8.1 CE - Memory leak issue

Tags: memory, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, mule

In the past few months our company's Mule was down twice - it happened when there were lots of traffic. To investigate, we did a load test to simulate a large number of users. I ran this test on my local machine with 512m application memory size, used JMeter to send request to Mule (Number of threads: 1000, ramp-up period: 10sec). And I use Visual VM to analyze.

Here are my observations:

- I see "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded" in Anypoint Studio's console.
- No error in mule log.
- [image: List item]
- I did a heap dump - it showed that the combined size of char array objects is really big.
- We see a very high number of AsyncLogger related classes: we now suspect we have a memory leak when writing logs.
- [image: List item]

When I changed all log level to Error, in order to remove all normal logs in log4j2.xml, the Garbage Collection performed correctly.

- [image]

Then I tried to use Mule Runtime 3.9.0 Community Version and reverted the log level change, I can see Garbage Collection was performing and number of threads go down when I stopped sending request to Mule.

- [image]

So why is there memory leak problem in 3.8.1? I checked 3.9.0 release notes - Resolved Issue checklist, I don't see any issue related to this issue. What is the root cause of the problem?

Answer (score 2):

[Log4j](https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-12541) was updated in Mule 3.8.5/3.9.0, that could be the reason. I suggest you take a look at all release notes in between 3.8.1 and 3.9.0 since the 3.9.0 release notes are based on the latest 3.8.x version at that point. In fact, you can find the update information in the [3.8.5](https://docs.mulesoft.com/release-notes/mule-3.8.5-release-notes) release notes. HTH